# Cannot run .exe app from virtual machine

Tags: linux, executable

I am trying to run the `.exe` of [an app](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/stockspy-real-time-quotes/id299972304) I have downloaded from the Apple store onto my virtual machine.

However, every time I run the file, I get the following error:

> cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

I have found a few articles suggesting what to do when this error occurs.

I have tried the following:

1. Installing Wine and then running the file with Wine. This gives me the alternative error [found here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/864649/ubuntu-wine-cannot-find-c-windows-system32). I could not solve this in the end.
2. Run the following:

   ```
   chmod u+x StockSpy
   ./StockSpy
   ```

   This does not work either.

Here's the system information of my Linux machine:

```
Linux instance-5 5.10.0-13-cloud-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.106-1 (2022-03-17) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: In 1, what is the alternative error that you actually got? I've looked at the link and it's unclear which of the many messages it references is the one you're meaning. Please edit your question. Do not reply to me here in a comment

Answer (score 2):

The app is for an iPhone. Unless you have either a real iPhone or an emulator for one you're not going to be able to run it. `wine` is for Microsoft Windows emulation, not Apple iPhone

Comment: Ah I see! I was looking into possible options like `Darling` however,  I was looking for the simplest solution that takes the least amount of hard-drive space. Unfortunately, Darling packs quite a punch. What other options do I have?

Comment: I've no idea what Darling might be, sorry